# "Unknown option: -hostfile" when using distributed TestNG

Tags: testng

i'd like to set up a distributed TestNG with 1 master PC and several slave PCs. But when i start the master with follwing command: 
    `java org.testng.TestNG -hostfile hosts.properties testng1.xml`
TestNG returns the error: 
    `Unknown option: -hostfile`
TestNG version is 6.1.1, haven't tried other version yet.
is this feature removed in this version?
any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checked TestNG codes, the option has been changed to "-master"